# Englische Wendung "food for thought" hat auf Deutsch verschiedene Möglichkeiten. Können alle synonym verwendet werden? Gibt es leichte Unterschiede?

Tags: meaning, english-to-german, difference, synonym

Im Englischen haben wir den Ausdruck "food for thought" verwendet, um ernsthaft über etwas nachzudenken.

Ich habe die englische Wendung "food for thought" im Wörterbuch dict.cc nachgeschlagen und habe diese Ergebnisse erhalten:

- Diese Substantive

  > Denkanstoß, Gedankenanstoß, Stoff zum Nachdenken, Denkanregung, Gedanken-Nahrung, Denkanregungen, Gedankenanstöße

  Können diese Substantive alle synonym verwendet werden?
- diesen Verben

  > jemanden nachdenklich stimmen; jemandem einen Denkanstoß/Denkanstöße geben

  Welche Unterschiede gibt zwischen diesen Verben?

Comment: Wass soll die Phrase *"Englische Wendung "food for thought" in the dictionary dict.cc nachschlagen"* bedeuten? Soll das eine Aufforderung an den Leser sein, diese Wendung nachzuschlagen? Warum schreibst du nicht selbst, welches Ergebnis man erhält, wenn man diese Wendung nachschlägt? Oder ist der Rest deines Postings bereits das Ergebnis dieser Recherche? In diesem Fall solltest du diese Phrase anderes formulieren, am besten als grammatisch vollständigen Satz, das würde Klarheit schaffen.

Comment: Added  "das war das Ergebnis"  hope that reads better.

Comment: Your question contained a lot of errors (In German we never have a space before a comma, Sentences always end with some interpunctation, "Nomen" and "Substantiv" are often used as synonyms, but they are not, "dictionary" is not a German word, and German nouns are always capitalized). I corrected that for you and I also brushed up the style of your posting. Feel free to undo some of my changes if you feel unhappy with them.

Comment: Edit seems perfect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die wörtlichste Übersetzung, die am besten dem eigentlichen Sinn von *food for thought* entspricht, ist **"Stoff zum Nachdenken"**. Damit liegst du auf jeden Fall richtig.

**"Denkanstoß"** ist ein sehr idiomatisches und beliebtes deutsches Wort, es betont ein bisschen mehr, dass es nur ein "Anstoß" (impulse, nudge) für eigene Gedanken ist, es kann eine kurze Idee oder ein einzelner Gedanke sein. Aber das ist ja m.E. im Englischen auch oft das, was man mit "food for thought" eigentlich ausdrücken möchte.

**"Gedanken-Nahrung"**: Ich will nicht ausschließen, dass deutsche Muttersprachler das vereinzelt benutzen, aber es klingt für mich wie ein spontan benutzter Anglizismus (Lehnübersetzung).

**"Gedankenanstoß/Gedankenanstöße", "Denkanregung/Denkanregungen"** sind nicht sehr idiomatisch, du wirst sie seltener hören. Als direkt falsch würde ich sie nicht bezeichnen, aber ich würde sie selbst nicht benutzen, sie klingen für mich, als sei jemandem das Wort "Denkanstoß" entweder nicht eingefallen, oder sie oder er hält es inzwischen für eine Phrase, die zu viel benutzt wird.

Die [Häufigkeitsstatistiken von DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=public&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1600%3A2018&q1=Denkansto%C3%9F&q2=Stoff%20zum%20Nachdenken&q3=Gedankenansto%C3%9F&q4=Denkanregung) zeigen "Stoff zum Nachdenken" als sehr beliebt um 1800 und immer noch populär bis heute. "Denkanstoß" kam demnach um 1930 auf und wurde schnell sehr populär. Die anderen Ausdrücke spielen im Vergleich keine Rolle.

[image: DWDS Verlaufskurve: Denkanstoß - Stoff zum Nachdenken - Gedankenanstoß - Denkanregung]

Zu den Verben:

**"Jdm. einen Denkanstoß / Denkanstöße geben"** ist richtig und bedeutet genau das, was man erwartet.

**"Jmd. nachdenklich stimmen"** kann man im gleichen Sinn benutzen. Wörtlich bedeutet es eher, dass man jemanden allgemein in eine nachdenkliche Stimmung *(contemplative mood)* versetzt, nicht so sehr, dass man ihn dazu bewegt, über etwas Bestimmtes nachzudenken. Es wird aber auch häufig benutzt, um auszudrücken, dass man jemanden, der vorher eine feste Ansicht hatte, dazu bringt, diese Ansicht in Frage zu stellen und zu beginnen, sie zu überdenken.

> Seine Tochter hat mit ihm über Kernenergie geredet und hat ihn nachdenklich gestimmt. *(meaning that she gave him some food for thought about his stance on nuclear energy)*

Comment: Excellent answer